# React.js way to emulate handlebars condition statements

Tags: reactjs, handlebars.js

I'm used to using Handlebars, what are some suggested React-y ways to emulate something like this (not necessarily a direct translation, but a similar effect):

```
var Beer = React.createClass({

  render: function(){

    return (

      <div className="media">
        <div className="media-body">
          {{#if beer.name}}<h4 className="media-heading">{beer.name}</h4>{{/if}}
          {{#if beer.icon}} <img className="media-object" src={beer.icon} />{{/if}}
          {{#if beer.style.name}}<p>{beer.style.name} </p>{{/if} 
            etc...
        </div>
      </div>

    )
  }
});


module.exports = Beer;
```

Comment: I'm currently working on: https://github.com/stevenvachon/handlebars-react

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simple conditions, you could use a technique like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wiredprairie/2mpw2khy/):

```
var Beer = React.createClass({    
  render: function(){    
    var beer = this.props.beer;        
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
            { beer.name ? <h4>{beer.name}</h4> : null }
            { beer.icon ? <img src={beer.icon} /> : null }
            { beer.style && beer.style.name ? <p>{ beer.style.name }</p> : null }
            { beer.style && beer.style.color ? <div>{ beer.style.color }</div> : null }
        </div>
      </div>    
    )
  }
});

var beer = {
    name: 'Pale Ale',
    style: {
        name: 'Very Very Pale'
    }
};

React.render(<Beer beer = { beer } />, 
              document.getElementById('content'));
```

I've just used the JavaScript conditional ternary operator to return an element if there's value at a specific property (although you'll want a slightly more robust string/value check than that ... I just wanted to keep it short to illustrate the point).

Answer (score 5):

My approach is slightly different from WiredPrarie's:

```
    var Beer = React.createClass({

      render: function(){

        return (

          <div className="media">
            <div className="media-body">
              { beer.name && <h4 className="media-heading">{beer.name}</h4> }
              { beer.icon && <img className="media-object" src={beer.icon} /> }
              { beer.style.name && <p>{beer.style.name} </p> } 
                etc...
            </div>
          </div>

        )
      }
    });


    module.exports = Beer;
```